# Access to C Drive in VBA

Tags: vba

```
Set f = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\tempcsv.csv", True)
DoCmd.TransferText , TableName:="Uploads", _
FileName:="c:\tempcsv.csv", HasFieldNames:=True
db.TableDefs.Refresh
fs.DeleteFile ("c:\tempcsv.csv")
```

I need to create this file but  VBA gives error that it cannot access it . How can I provide permission to VBA to access the C drive.

Thanks

Comment: UAC (Windows Vista and above) do not allow non-administrators to write to the root of the drive. The proper solution: Don't write to the root of the drive, but instead write to a location where you have permission to write such as the user's Documents folder.

Comment: I want to use it generally on many computers, so I cant  include the user name right? is there any path unanimous to all the computers

Comment: `path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")`

Comment: `"C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\documents\"` is another option.